# Install private TFS repo with poetry

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs, python-poetry

Has anyone had luck installing a private repo hosted on Team Foundation Server using poetry?

The repo has the URL of form `tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}.`

I am able to run `pip install git+http://tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}@{branchName}` and install the package this way. I would like to install the package via poetry so it shows up in the pyproject.toml file.

Attempts:

1a. `poetry add git+http://tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}@{branchName}`

Returns:
`Could not parse version constraint: //tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}@{branchName}`

1b. Using https instead of http: `poetry add git+https://tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}@{branchName}`

Returns:
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tfs', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:`

2.

```
poetry source add tmpName http://tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/
poetry config http-basic.tmpName <user> <pass>
poetry add --source tmpName {repo}#{branchName}
```

Returns:

```
Source (tfs): Authorization error accessing http://tfs/tfs/{CollectionName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{repo}#{branchName}/

Could not find a matching version of package {repo}#{branchName}
```